# jquery ajax call data.d returns undefined

Tags: json, wcf, jquery

[{"Emp_name":"admin","GIN_no":"001","Mode":"1"},{"Emp_name":"MMMK","GIN_no":"1792","Mode":"1"}]

this is my json return from wcf service when accessed from browser `http://localhost/ddd/hostedService.svc/getEmployee` like this.

when i tried to access the returned json from jquery the d object returns undefined. 
my ajax looks like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost/ddd/hostedService.svc/getEmployee",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                datatype: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    myFunction(data.d);

                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });
        function myFunction(ajaxValue) {
            alert(ajaxValue.Emp_name)
        }
```

the alert data returns {object,object}.... like this.

i am not sure where i am missing. any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Such a dumb fellow i am, the json is returning a set of data as you can see the first line as array, just i have to use an each function to iterate through it and i am able to see list.
so here is the working code

```
                    var items = [];

                            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                                items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val.Emp_name + '</li>');
                            });

                            $('<ul/>', {
                                html: items.join('')
                            }).appendTo('body');
                        });
```